# How to Convert Open Image Dataset to LMDB

Tags: caffe, lmdb

I am currently working in Caffe framework. To create a caffe model, I need to create a LMDB file from image dataset. The image dataset I am using is Open Images. for that I have downloaded the open image dataset from [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/2017_07/images_2017_07.tar.gz), etc.
When extracted I'm getting csv files. 
How should I convert the Open image dataset to LMDB format? Please help me, I'm blocked here for days.

Hey 
i have gone through the reverse post you redirected to, but it doesn't say anything about creation of train.txt file. do we simply give the image location and some labels to it?

img_0000.jpeg 1
img_0001.jpeg 0
img_0002.jpeg 0

What does this 1, 0, 0, labels with each images points to?, doesn't it have any meaning? what category are you mentioning here? 1 means what category? 0 means means what?